# Weka Knowledgeflow - Database not loading after saving

Tags: weka

I made a model in Weka Knowledgeflow, ran it a couple of times and it works as a champ! Now a day later I opened the saved Knowledgeflow model again, but it is not working any more. It seems like no data is been pulled from the DatabaseLoader I have used.

```
16:08:51: [Loader] DatabaseLoader$12241592|-url " jdbc:mysql://url-to-website.com:3306/BIPM" -user BIPM -password secret- -Q "SELECT * FROM customers" -P| null
```

No settings have been changes, the database has remained the same. Also in the Weka Explorer itself importing the database with same settings is working.

Is there something I have missed? I seems like after I saved the model I stopped working..